Using AWS SSO with .NET Core app running in Docker Compose
I am trying to get a service that is written in .NET 8 and running on Docker Compose 3 to use my AWS SSO credentials when communicating with AWS services (in this case, SQS).
My AWS config file is defined as:
[default]
region = ap-southeast-2

[sso-session lets-go]
sso_start_url=https://my-org-entrypoint.awsapps.com/start
sso_region=ap-southeast-2
sso_registration_scopes=sso:account:access

[profile non-prod]
sso_session=lets-go
sso_account_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx
sso_role_name=DeveloperAccess

and my docker-compose.yml is
name: 'my-product'
services:
  my-service:
    build:
      dockerfile: src/my-app/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - AWS_PROFILE=non-prod
      - AWS_REGION=ap-southeast-2
      - AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/app/.aws/config
      - AWS_SSO_SESSION=lets-go
    volumes:
      - ~/.aws:/app/.aws:ro

I'm mounting the .aws folder to /app instead of /root because my Docker image is running as non-root user, but I've tried mounting it to /root just in case, without success.
I sign in via SSO, then start the application:
aws sso login --profile non-prod
docker compose up -d

The container starts up and I see the following in its logs:
[23:49:43 INF] Initiating startup
[23:49:43 INF] Found credentials using the AWS SDK's default credential search
[23:49:45 ERR] Error while initialising queue
  Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.
    at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials()
    at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentials()
    at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentialsAsync()
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
    at OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AWS.Implementation.AWSPropagatorPipelineHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
    at OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AWS.Implementation.AWSTracingPipelineHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)

If I go into Docker Desktop and explore the container, I can see all the files from the .aws folder have been correctly mounted in the expected location.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I think we're trying to do the same thing David, are you able to see the .aws folder within your container?

Yes, and I can browse it and see all the expected files. I've raised an issue with the AWS SDK team: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/3438
